# C Code using Glib library building succesfully on windows gives compiler/linker error on linux

Tags: c, linux, window, glib, gobject

I have a code which makes use of Glib library to create a new type. Now the code is as:

`.h` file:

```
G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE(NewTypeState, new_type_state, NEW, TYPE_STATE, ParentType)
```

`.c` file:

```
G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_PRIVATE(NewTypeState, new_type_state, NEW_TYPE_STATE)
```

now as per the [glib doc](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject-construction.html) for object creation we have to define two static functions as:

```
static new_type_init()

static new_type_class_init()
```

But in the code instead of defining static new_type_init() the func. is declared as:

```
__declspec(dllexport) extern void new_type_init()
```

and defined as:

```
void new_type_init()
{}
```

And the code compiles and links successfully on windows but while trying to build on linux I removed the `__declspec(dllexport)` but I started getting the error:

> static declaration follows non-static declaration

**Now I commented out the declaration from .h file and only has non-static definition in the .c file but when trying to build it I get the linker error:**

> undefined reference **new_type_init**

I even added the **extern** to definition but the error stays.

Could someone explain the above behavior?

EDIT:

o/p for `objdump -t <file-name> | grep -i <symbol-name>` is:

```
000000000000b440 l     F .text  0000000000000023              symbol-name
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000              symbol-name
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but your G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE uses the class itself as the parent class: that seems wrong

Comment: "extern static" is like saying "local global" or "I want a red car with blue color". Use the one you actually need, not both.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: @Lundin the code has `extern`only. I was referring to glib documentation which suggests that method should be defined with `static` storage class and no need to declare the method. It seems glib macro takes care of that. But interestingly the function is declared with __declspec(dllexport)extern and then also defined as non-static and it works with MSV c compiler as the code is building successfully on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Extern indicates the function will be available later (i.e. is not defined here in this translation unit). Static forces the function to be unavailable externally. Add extern to the declaration in the header and remove static from the definition and you may have some success. That being said, I do not know Glib so cannot say for sure.

Comment: I have mentioned that the method definition is non-static and also I tried with `extern` but the error remains.

Comment: So you did! Can you please add the command line used to link. You should be able to see this with a verbose flag set. In cmake world, this would be achieved with `make VERBOSE=1` iirc.

Comment: I used `make VERBOSE=1` and can see`/usr/bin/c++` command which is creating the `.so` having the `.o` files containing the above functions. Are you referring to that when you mentioned -  `Can you please add the command line used to link`?

Comment: Yeah. Interesting that c++ is used not cc, I wonder if this is a name mangling issue, and that in fact it would make sense to add `extern "C" ...` in the header ....

Comment: There is one .cpp file but the symbols which linker is not able to find are all part of .c files. And as extern "C" can't be used in .c files I am not sure if name-mangling is happening. /usr/bin/c++ might be beacuse of .cpp file and c compiler won't be able to compile it. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sounds right. That will then cause the stdlib to be pulled in, but as you say, you don't need to worry about mangling for the c files. The link line should mention a bunch of .o files. One of which corresponds to the c module where you defined the unit function. We can look inside that to see if it is defined and available externally. Can you see the .o file referenced in the link line?

Comment: Yes the .o file is referenced there. But when I use `nm <file-name> | grep -i <symbol-name>` then i can see `000000000000b440 t <symbol-name>
                 U <symbol-name>`

Comment: Also I have posted the `objdump -t <file-name> | grep -i <symbol-name>` command `o/p` in the question itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205811/discussion-between-wobr-and-yug-singh).